# Get All Strings After URL in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.5 and have a question about routing.

My route is like this

```
Route::get('/folder/{param}', 'PageController@getFolderTree');
```

And I want to get all parameters after /folder/:

http://example.com/folder/com/example/app -> I get /example/app

How can it possible ?

Comment: `function getFolderTree($params){//here you can access params}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know in advance what the maximum number of parameters will be you can do one of the next 2.

a) If [all are neccessery](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#required-parameters):

```
Route::get('/folder/{a}/{b}/{c}', 'PageController@getFolderTree');
```

b) If [not all are neccessery](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#parameters-optional-parameters):

```
Route::get('/folder/{a?}/{b?}/{c?}', 'PageController@getFolderTree');
```

And retrieve them like this:

```
public function getFolderTree($a, $b, $c) {...}
```

And if you don't know the maximum you will need to do a regex and explode. This would be the route:

```
Route::get('/folder/{any}', 'PageController@getFolderTree')
    ->where('any', '.*'); // Indicates that {any} can be anything
```

And do the explode in the controller:

```
public function getFolderTree($any) {
{
    $params = explode('/', $any); // $params will be an array of params
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `explode` the URL. For example:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/folder/com/example/app';
$explodedText = explode('/folder/', $url);
$textBeforeFolder = $explodedText[0];
$textAfterFolder = $explodedText[1]; // This is the one you want
```

Answer (score 0):

```
request->url() //will return the whole url
```

and

```
request()->uri() //will return the URI
```

Now if you want to access the full URL u can access

```
request()-fullUrl() //will return the full url
```

Now you can use `str_replace()`

```
 str_replace(request()->url.'folder/com/','', request->fullUrl());

 //it will return example/app
```